Tree Branches extrude out then in according to wire frame
The tree branches extrude out, and then back inwards, or are they simply confused about start and finish? i.e. which end is which? I am not sure how to fix this as I followed a guide that did not go to well when it came to the "transfer attribute node" which is now change to the sample node feature.
Can someone point me in the right direction please?


If you could provide your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question... because most of us are probably not willing to try deciphering the small letters in your screenshot to rebuild the complete nodetree to check where it goes wrong...

https://blend-exchange.com/b/zW77jXQg
